# jQuery scrollTop viewport issue. How to add a custom value to position().top

Tags: jquery, html, position, viewport, scrolltop

I'm developing a single page wordpress website. As it is a single page one I have used jQuery scrollTop for animating the menu. I want to go to specific div when I click on the corresponding menu link with div id.. 
Current Problem is the fixed positioned menu tab is crossing the content.. It shows over the div content (viewport issue).

I want to give a gap between this menu tab and div content for making the content fully visible.

jQuery code used for scrolling effect is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a[href=#welcome]').click(function(){

     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#welcome').position().top}, 'slow');

     return false;

    });



});


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a[href=#aboutus]').click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#aboutus').position().top}, 'slow');

     return false;

  });

});
```

What I need is to add some value like 200px to the above div's top position ".position().top}" so that I can scroll to a position below the top of the div...

Edit:"Sorry Guys... I made a mistake in above requirement.. I have to subtract a value from the div's top position so that I can scroll to a position above the top of the div.."

How can i fix this? Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the height of the menu, for example:

```
var menuHeight = $('#mainMenu').height();
```

When you do the scroll on line:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#aboutus').position().top}, 'slow');
```

You subtract the menu height:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#aboutus').position().top-menuHeight}, 'slow');
```

Not tested, but I think it should work.
Basically you say to scroll to your div position but to a position before that position which would be the menu height.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your help.. Your assumption was correct! I used position().top-175 . But now I came to know that my above code was not working -> $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#aboutus').position().top-menuHeight}, 'slow'); it simply scrolls to that div as in html code only.. jquery animation not working.. i got some other code and used your suggestion in it.. And Now It Works.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I completely understand, but you can add 200 (since its in px) to your position.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var marginTop = 200;  // add or remove or even grab the position of another element

   $('a[href=#aboutus]').click(function(){
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#aboutus').position().top + marginTop}, 'slow');
         return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Let's say your #aboutus div position is 1000px
if you 'add' the marginTop you will get more than the scroll should do.
You should subtract instead of add (i think).

Comment: This all depends on the person's elements.  You should just get the element's position and set it.  The variable to be negative or positive to adjust it to his likings.  A screen shot and some html would clarify his question.

Comment: True...
I assumed he has the menu at top :)